# How to automatically show component values in Altium (Manufacturer Part Search)?

Tags: schematics, altium

I just noticed that Altium 20 is free for students (yay). I'm trying to get used to it again, i was using Altium 17 during an internship for quite some time - with an already very big and well maintained library.

Now, I discovered that there is the "manufacturer part search", but I have a very stupid issue with it:

When I place a component discovered in this part search, it does not show the component value (e.g. resistance or capacity). I know how to turn it on part by part, but is it possible to enable it globally?

Thank your very much!

All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you placed most of your components in the schematic:

1. right click on one Part -> Find similar
2. objects Object Kind = Part -> set to "Same"
3. ensure that "Select Matched" is checked (ON) (at the bottom)
4. OK

Now all components are selected.

Go to properties tab and click on the "eye" icon of each parameter you want to show or hide.

Shift + C clear the selection afterwards.